# Why does using std::regex make compile times go up alot?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, compile-time

So I have this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    //std::regex r("test");

    std::cout << "\n============ end ==============" << std::endl;
    return 0;    
}
```

On godbolt this compiles in around 2-2.5 seconds (sometimes much faster): https://godbolt.org/z/m5SY4s

But then when I add a usage of regex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::regex r("test");

    std::cout << "\n============ end ==============" << std::endl;
    return 0;    
}
```

Now on godbolt it takes around 5 seconds: https://godbolt.org/z/KcZFSz

**Note:** to see this for your selves on the links in godbolt you might need to hit the clear cache and re-compile button (its a little recycle circle arrow icon on the bottom right panel, in the bottom status bar of that panel. Also in the status bar you will see time in milliseconds.

I have found this in my code. I use lots of different parts of the c++ libraries - but nothing else has this much effect - not even closed. I am getting two files that are just really slow to compile (a few seconds each), all my other files are < 1 second.

I removed a few lines in both of these files (to do with regex) and now they also build nice and fast.

1. So, why is this? - I guess regex is very large?, but it would have to be huuuuuge, right? - I just don't see it being that big. There must be other parts of the c libs that are large also and I use a lot of parts of the c libs.
2. Is there anything I can do about it? - or just don't use regex?

I tried added  into a pre-compiled header, it did not have much effect though.

Comment: `std::regex r("test")` instantiate the class (which was only "parsed").

Comment: A regex is expensive.  You need to build a finite state machine to handle the expression and that will probably involve templates and that can increase compile times.

Comment: I understand that creating / instantiating a regex object means it has to create a concrete instance of the regex template. But is it really so much more work then, say... std::thread, std::map/vector/deque/stack std::functional and so on... I am using threads, lambdas, chronos, STLs etc... all over the place, but none of these are taking anywhere near as long to compile... I mean, if it is, then it is... but....wow!, its sooooo much more work for the compiler it is very surprising to me :o

Comment: Compile time ? who care, runtime start is all worry. Advize: keep all (or most) global reggex seperate file that is all inited at runtime startup. `const.h extern std::regex MyRx;

const.cpp MyRx = std::regex("here") ;`

Comment: @Edward "Compile time ? who care"....well.... me : )  I have put a lot of effort into my make file system to maximise parallelism and minimise duplicate work. I am currently looking into pre-compiled headers, which helps me get most of my files well below 1s compile time (100-200ms mostly). But these regex files are over 2 seconds. It just bothers me, I can probably find another solution - but I want to know what is going on and why is so slow - if for no other reason then curiosity : )

Comment: because regex header is about 150 KB - its big. This is one of the biggest stl headers. The more code the compiler has to look at, the longer it takes to compile. Add #include <regex> to a precompiled header (include it in "stdafx.h")

Comment: @dgrandm In the very last line of my Q I mention that I had already added it to a precompiled header (using gcc). The saving appeared to be minimal. My precompiled header is ~70MB and `-Winvalid-pch` gives no warning and `-H` shows only the precompiled header is included, so not directly including <regex>, only through the pch.h.gch file (gcc's precompiled header output). Maybe I need to create a usage in my precompiled header? - like `std::regex bob;` just to get that invoked within the header.. not sure.. still can't figure out a way to speed it up. Thanks for the size update, regex is big!

Comment: in MSVC there is a compiler flag to use precompiled header or to generate it. With gcc there got to be something similar. Maybe you need to play around with these flags. I do not think that creating a usage of include files added to precompiled header will affect the speed of compilation.

Comment: @dgrandm .... umm, ok let me try a third time: **I have already used precompiled headers using gcc** : )  it might shave a hundred milliseconds or so, but any usage of regex adds over 1 second to the compile time.